# Getting exception 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(Can not create a Path from an empty string)' while issuing select query in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am new to this site and actually i am stuck with below issue getting "can not create a path from an empty string" error. My hadoop version is 2.5.2 and hive version is 0.13.1. Below are the file details and my query I have used, can anyone help me to fix this thanks.

**Filename**: tweet_info.json
**Data in the file as below**:

```
{
    "user": {
        "lang": "en",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
        "id_str": "568286862",
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "statuses_count": 595,
        "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
        "favourites_count": 5,
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2206373396\/image_normal.jpg",
        "following": null,
        "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
        "description": "Nobody can ever affect you unless you allow yourself to be affected.",
        "notifications": null,
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "time_zone": null,
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "listed_count": 0,
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "created_at": "Tue May 01 13:29:22 +0000 2012",
        "screen_name": "Chin_Hean",
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "protected": false,
        "url": null,
        "default_profile": true,
        "name": "\u0106hr\u00ed\u0161",
        "is_translator": false,
        "show_all_inline_media": false,
        "verified": false,
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "followers_count": 37,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2206373396\/image_normal.jpg",
        "id": 568286862,
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
        "utc_offset": null,
        "friends_count": 65,
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "location": "Stark Industries"
    }
}
```

### **My create table query in Hive**:

```
CREATE TABLE tweet_info(
user struct<lang: string, id: int, statuses_count: int, favourites_count: int, description: string, 
screen_name: string, url: string, friends_count: int, followers_count: int, location: string>)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde';
```

### **My Select query**:

```
SELECT user.id UserId, user.screen_name UserName, user.location UserLocation, user.description UserDescription, user.lang UserLanguage, user.friends_count UserFrndsCount from tweet_info;
```

### **Error log**:

Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1088)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(Can not create a Path from an empty string)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

Comment: I think the message is prety clear `Can not create a Path from an empty string
`

Comment: Why don't you use `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe`?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks 4ur suggestion but I have used 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde' instead and got rid of the error. Now I am getting a new error as below:Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure out the solution for my problem. Below are the changes I made which resolved all of my errors.

1. I replaced my serde with hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2. Placed
   the above jar into my hive/lib folder as below:
   '/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-0.13.1-bin/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
3. Add the jar to my classpath: add jar
   /usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-0.13.1-bin/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
4. I changed ROW FORMAT SERDE to 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
   in my Create table query.

this resolved all my errors and finally got my output.

Thanks